# BS4 only down not return entire webpage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble correctly reading the below site. If I use Qt4 to convert it to HTML and print 'content' I get the entire page in HTML back, however when I try to read it using bs4 it only returns half the page...?

```
url = 'http://www.scorespro.com/formula1/monaco-grand-prix-2013/race/'

class Render(QtWebKit.QWebPage):
    print 'dfasadf'
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        QtWebKit.QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()

r = Render(url)
content = unicode(r.frame.toHtml())
content = content
web_soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
print content, web_soup
```

would anyone know why this is..?

Comment: Did you check if the HTML is well-formed before passing it to BeautifulSoup? Or tried to specify a different parser in BeautifulSoup constructor?

Comment: This won't help, but I had a problem like this yesterday. My code works on one machine (Windows, 32bit-Python), but not on the other (Linux, 64bit-Python). Same Version of BS4 and lxml on both machines.